# Creating a Movies Windows Phone 7 Application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I'm planning to create an application for my college assignment in windows phone 7 which is a `movie release date finder`. The application is supposed to find upcoming movies, recently released movies, find movie date by name and vice versa.

I don't know where to start by. Which site should I retrieve the information from, nor how to do it.I did see some of the sample codes but dint find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Creating the backend

In [this other So question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787808/is-there-any-online-free-movie-information-apis) you'll find an answer pointing to [The Movie DB](http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/), an online movie API, though I haven't tried it myself either. As per how to code your app, there's no much we can help you with unless you have an idea of what you want to achieve, also note that for every data source you use then there's probably a different way to retrieve information.

You should start by writing down all the features you want your app to have, then create your backend, preferably in a project of its own, defining all the classes that compose your whole model. You can also have a 2nd project that handles all the data retrieval and just use the back-end project as a POCO-classes repository.

In this second project, if you decide to split it like that, is where you'll implement all the logic to retrieve information from `The Movie DB`, or any other data source you use, the advantage to this approach is that if that API were to come down, then you could easily recode this project to use another source without affecting the rest of your application.

### Creating the UI

For the UI you should start by creating some mockups, there are many free tools for this you can google, if the app is going to be really informal then you can even do the mockups old school with pen and paper. Then create the UI as you defined it in your mockups, at [Windows Phone Dev](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us) you'll find a lot of tutorials and useful info on creating UIs.